# Prevent text from breaking into new line

Tags: html, css

How can I prevent my text breaking like this:

[image: like this]

My code:

```css
#livbar {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  width: 70%;
  border: #222;
  background-color: #222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="livbar">
  <p style="color: #d5d2d2; font: 11px 'PT Sans', sans-serif;">TEST:</p>
  <p style="color: #c0ac7f; font: 11px 'PT Sans', sans-serif; white-space: nowrap;">100%</p>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: just add display:inline; to your p element

Answer (score 1):

Solved, added `display: inline` to the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to see the text breaking into two lines, because you are using a `<p>` element for each word, and `<p>` stands for a new pragraph which will automatically break line.

If you want to display the two words inline you best use a `<span>` element for each word, because spans shows inline.

But if you insist on using `<p>` elements adding `display:inline;` to it's style will do the trick.